# How to read inputs (int) in Termbox?

Tags: go, terminal, command, command-line-interface

How to read inputs (int) in termbox? I'm trying to make a terminal application written in Go. All I have is termbox's demos apps and doc on termbox.

Comment: you can check this [example](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go/blob/master/_demos/keyboard.go) from termbox which shows how to take input from keyboard

Comment: this keyboard app contains all the keys. Do I have to connect all the keys to get inputs?

Comment: if you do not require all then you can skip it depends on the requirement